# JMeter doesn't work on local machine when connecting to remote servers

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm having some problems when trying to run a JMeter test using some remote machines. When I do a simple test on my local machine, it works really well.

The problem comes when I try to launch my test using my machine and two other servers.

It woks weel when I launch

> ./jmeter -n -t ../../script.jmx -l ../../results.csv -e -o ../../report -Jthroughput=200 -Jduration=30 -Jvmnb=3 -q ../../propertiesFile.properties

But if I do

> ./jmeter -n -t ../../script.jmx -l ../../results.csv -e -o ../../report -Jthroughput=200 -Jduration=30 -Jvmnb=3 -q ../../propertiesFile.properties -r -X

Or

> ./jmeter -n -t ../../script.jmx -l ../../results.csv -e -o ../../report -Jthroughput=200 -Jduration=30 -Jvmnb=3 -q ../../propertiesFile.properties -R127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.175, 192.168.1.15 -X

I'm having the error

> Following remote engines could not be configured:[127.0.0.1]

And if I take out the local machine

> ./jmeter -n -t ../../script.jmx -l ../../results.csv -e -o ../../report -Jthroughput=200 -Jduration=30 -Jvmnb=3 -q ../../propertiesFile.properties -R192.168.1.175, 192.168.1.15 -X

It also works well on the two other servers (but it ignores my propertiesFile.properties file).

I've tried to deal with it for 2 days now, I really don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are running jemter-server on your local host before you run the test.

Check your jmeter-server.log to see if there are any errors.

You have to use -G to send the properties to the remote servers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I check if the server si running? If I do a ./jmeter-server in my localhost, I can't launch my command line, because it stays in a waiting mode...

Comment: Ok, I can add a "&" at the end of the line... :)
Thanks again